# Zend Framework 2 Routing Part of the action name based on route segment

Tags: url-routing, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

Is there a way to set up a route in ZF2 (Segment or otherwise) so that `/staff/list` translates to the `staffListAction()` action in my controller?

Typically /staff-list translates to staffListAction. Is there a way to change that delimiter?

I saw this on Evan Coury's blog, but it talks about a segment, not exactly an action.

[Changing segment delimeter](http://evan.pro/zf2-router-talk.html#slide18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pretty much would be a route of type `literal`. Something like

```
'staff' => array(
    'type' => 'literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/staff',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'namespace-controller-staff',
            'action' => 'index'
        )
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'list' => array(
            'type' => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/list',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'staffList'
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

Didn't try it, but i assume it works. Personally i run with literal routes as much as possible, as they are the fastest to match.

Comment: Right, that would probably work. I was just trying to be lazy since I'm going to have several of those.

Example: staff/list, client/list, vendor/list, etc. All doing similar things, but returning different views and calling on different tables.